# Exception in thread "main" exception: input

Tags: arrays, exception, indexing

why is my code showing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at arraytest.main(arraytest.java:27) whenever i run it , although It doesn't show any redlined errors? IndexOutOfBoundsException: number changes according to number of students entered.. ???

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class arraytest {




public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    int numStudents;
    System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");
    Scanner scanint = new Scanner (System.in);      
    numStudents = scanint.nextInt();
    int [] grades = new int [numStudents]; //the size we wanted




    for ( i = 0;  i < grades.length; ++i) //starting from 0, not 1.
    {



        sum += grades[numStudents];

        System.out.println("Enter grade: ");

        grades[i] = scanint.nextInt();
    } 
    //print the array - for checking out everyting is ok

        sum /= numStudents ;
    System.out.println(sum);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for-loop is incorrect, change it to:

```
 for ( i = 0;  i < grades.length; ++i) //starting from 0, not 1.
    {
        System.out.println("Enter grade: ");
        grades[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        sum += grades[i];
    }
```

Reason for Exception: on first iteration, it enters for-loop and `sum += grades[numStudents]` throws the exception, because `numStudents` is constant, and it is the length of the array, actual elements in an array are from index 0 to (size -1). You should use the loop variable `i`.